# How to Load data from DB2 to Teradata

Tags: db2, teradata

I am new to Teradata and DB2 but not new to Data migration. I have done a lot of Data Migration in SQL server using tooling provided by Microsoft. As we know that DB2 is IBM product and Teradata is very famous Data warehousing but I cannot find any tooling provided these database to export Data from DB2 database to Teradata hence why I am here. I know there is IBM Sphere but I need to buy a license for that so I am also open for any open source technology.

Comment: This sounds like basic ETL and there are a lot of tools out there to help with this. Since you are migrating data INTO teradata, I would suggest that you stick with a Teradata Utility or an ETL tool that uses the native Teradata Utilities under the hood. Once could write their own Teradata TPT script that utilizes an ODBC connection DB2 to consume the data, but there a lot of options here.

Comment: Can you please provide the list of tools? and thanks a lot for giving the valuable tip

Comment: Is your DB2 on a mainframe? Is your mainframe channel connected to Teradata? Etc. Lots of variables and solutions based on those variables.

Comment: Yes it is on a mainframe. I'm not sure if my mainframe channel connected to teradata but what are the options if it is connected or not?

Comment: If you have the Teradata Tools and Utilities installed on the mainframe, once the data is extracted from DB2 it can be loaded into Teradata using Teradata Parallel Transport or a legacy utility such as FastLoad or MultiLoad. Alternatively if your organization had an ETL tool, you can use it. I would speak with your DBAs for both platforms to understand what options exist in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the lead and specifying tooling support. I will talk to DBAs